# using PHP explode() of a unicode string to get the rows in an array

Tags: php, utf-8

I am trying to read a tab delimited spreadsheet with unicode characters like this:

```
$content =      file_get_contents($filename);
```

When I print this in the browser are texts are shown correctly. Also there is a header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Now I want to split the content into rows by using:

```
$rows=  explode("\n",$content);
```

The content for the unicode characters now is gibberish when I for instance print one row:

```
echo $rows[1];
```

My question is: what is causing this behaviour and what can I do to get the correct texts into the $row array? In the end I want to insert the row values into the database, which currently now inserts the gibberish.

help appreciated

**Example**

A row before the explode() looks like this (note: tabs are not displayed below):

> R002  Студия 2В   66 Богдан
>   дорога                Санкт-Петербург 3174        45      Андрей      Смирнов     маркетинг   234-56790   653-23685       dummy@dummy.com 34354547

After the explode a row looks like:

> R002 ! B C 4 8 O  2   66   > 3 4 0 =  4 > @ > 3 0  ! 0 = : B -¬ 5 B 5
>   @ 1 C @ 3  3174 45   = 4 @ 5 9  ! < 8 @ = > 2  < 0 @ : 5 B 8 = 3 
>   234-56790 653-23685 dummy@dummy.com 34354547 59

**Edit: Also substring not working**

I noted also another strange behavious. When I do

```
echo mb_substr($content,0,50,'utf-8');
```

the output is only 25 characters, but characters are displayed correctly

> R002  Студия 2В   66 Богдан

However when I change the offset form 0 to for instance 5 it's a mess again.

```
echo mb_substr($content,5,50,'utf-8');
```

the output is

> 02 ! B C 4 8 O  2   66   > 3 4 0 =  4 >

not sure what's going on here ... Can it be because the file contains a utf-8 bom ("\xEF\xBB\xBF")?

Comment: Show your content and expected output

Comment: I've added an example now :-)

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Hi, The expected output is that when I want to print a row (echo $rows[1]) that was exploded based on a newline (explode("\n",$content)) that the unicode characters remain the same as displayed in $content.


In the end each row will be inserted into a database after validation.

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-split.php

Comment: explode() works fine for UTF-8 data, especially when exploding on an ASCII character as you're doing. Something else must be wrong. Also, you should strip the BOM regardless.

Comment: Without knowing the actual content of the string in memory, it's impossible to answer what the problem is. Please provide example code sufficient for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems that when I remove the BOM using Notepad++ the file works fine. However the file was created in MS-Excel using BOM using UCS-2 Little Endian. Is there a way to remove any BOM from a string?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, which had to to with it's encoding. It was exported from Excel which offered initial difficulties. Anyways here is my code to resolve the encoding bit:

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);

if (strpos($data, "\xef\xbb\xbf") !== FALSE) 
{
    //do nothing, it's already utf-8
}
elseif(strpos($data, "\xff\xfe") !== FALSE) 
{
    $data = iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', $data); //LE UTF-16
}
elseif(strpos($data, "\xfe\xff") !== FALSE) 
{
    $data = iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', $data); //BE UTF-16
}
```